# Dont insert with Nodejs Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m getting a problem with Mongoose Nodejs

This is my code for Controllers to Insert user in the database using Schema User from imported another file.

```
  router.post('/insert', function insertUsert(req, res){

    var newUser =  User({
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username, 
        password: req.body.password, 
        admin: false        
     });
     newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          res.status(400).send(err);
        }else{
          res.status(201).send("User Inserted)");
        }
     })
    });
```

This is my connection Mongoose:

```
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/trabbel';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    dbURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://<>:<>@ds133465.mlab.com:33465/locations';
    mongoose.connect(dbURI);

    console.log(dbURI);
}

// CONNECTION EVENTS

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {    
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);    
});
```

When I execute with Postman in the Route:

```
POST /user/insert - - ms - -
```

Comment: Did you forget `new` before `User`? => `var newUser = new User({`

Comment: Do you get the `Mongoose connected to ...` console message?

Comment: @JohnnyHK dont get any message from connection, only when i disconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

That pass a reference of function in router.post

```
    router.post('/insert', insertUsert);

    function insertUsert(req, res, next){
        const newUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username, 
            password: req.body.password, 
            admin: false

         })

newUser.save().then(function(user) {

    if(err) res.status(400).json({"message": err})
    res.status(200).json(user)

})
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.connect` is inside a condition that runs only on production, turn it to:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    dbURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://<>:<>@ds133465.mlab.com:33465/locations';
}
mongoose.connect(dbURI);
console.log(dbURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this adjustment to your code will make it work. I figured out you forgot the `new` keyword in creating the instance of your user model. I believe that will fix your problem.

```js
 router.post('/insert', function insertUsert(req, res, next){

    var newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username, 
        password: req.body.password, 
        admin: false

     });
     newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          return next(err);
        }
        res.status(201).send("User Inserted)");
     })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code. while inserting, you need to use new keyword

```
router.post('/insert', function insertUsert(req, res, next){

    new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username, 
        password: req.body.password, 
        admin: false

     }).save(function(err, user){
        if(err){
          return next(err);
        }
        res.status(201).send("User Inserted)");
     })
    });
```

Comment: can u share your request and response details

Comment: the request its  postman with x-www-form-urlencoded with keys username, user, password to ./user/insert